# How to extract data from datatable in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

```
 DataTable _dtDetail = DaoTraining.GetTrainingDetail(App.UserName_str, App.ServerIP);

 radGrid_PackGroup.ItemsSource = _dtDetail;
```

This populates into a datatable. I need to extract data from this table and store it into a string array, splitting the extracted data at ",(comma)" as a string.

How to go about doing that?

Comment: So in other words you want to dump the entire content of the datatable in a comma separated string. What about separating one row from the next?

Comment: Yes. The datatable has only two rows, and both the rows contain data like "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff....zz" and "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd....zzz". I want to use a loop for each row and extract the value as a string and fill it into a string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
string[] details = _dtDetail.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<string>("ColumnName")).ToArray<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I kind of did it myself. If anyone wants they can reference this code.

```
string[] _dtNumber;
    int count=0;

            for (int i=0; i<_dtDetail.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {

                _dtNumber = _dtDetail.Rows[i][1].ToString().Split(',');

                count = _dtNumber.Length;

                _dtDetail.Rows[i][1] = count.ToString();
            }



            radGrid_PackGroup.ItemsSource = _dtDetail;
```